# Receiving messages from server in python

Tags: python, server, tcp, client

I'm trying show all the messages the server is sending my client and I'm really not sure how to do that properly.

```
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                # connects socket
                s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 2000))
                msg = s.recv(1024)
```

That is how I get one message for now but I would like to receive a message every time the server sends something. Should I use a while loop?

EDIT: I tried this while loop:

```
        while True:
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 2000))
                try:
                    msg = s.recv(1024)
                    print(msg)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'{e}')
                    pass
```

And I'm getting an endless stream of:
b'N,C\n'
b'N,C\n'
b'N,C\n'
b'N,C\n'
.
.
.

Meaning nothing to send in this server.

EDIT2:
Tried to change the while location now I get b'N,C\n' one time.

```
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 2000))
        try:
            while True:
                msg = s.recv(1024)
                print(f'In the while: {msg}')
                time.sleep(0.5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'{e}')
            pass
```

Comment: A `while` loop sounds like a great idea. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I just tried that now and i get endless messages: b'N,C\n'
b'N,C\n'
b'N,C\n'
b'N,C\n'. in this server that is saying nothing to send. something like that

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Ok, this is not your code, but it looks like the `while` is in the wrong place. It should be after the `s.connect(...`, but enclose the `try/except`.

Comment: Yes, I see your latest edit. With the `while` enclosing the whole of your code, your client receives data from the server, prints it, sleeps, then closes the socket and the `while` starts the whole thing over again by opening a new socket to the server.

Comment: I can remove the try/except for now 

Comment: So your second edit. If you comment out the `while True:` does it work the same as the first snippet?

Comment: I was wrong sorry. I get "b'N,C\n'" one time when I put the while and when I remove it.

Comment: So, now the code will have looped round waiting in the `recv()` method for the next message from the server.